# Outlook 2010 bad images in newsletter

Tags: html, css, image, outlook-2010, newsletter

Helo,

I'm creating html newsletter with a few images as background (whole background, background under the content etc.)

I googled out this http://backgrounds.cm/ which allows me to set background images to 'td' elements.

It works fine as you can see here: http://www.braun-it.cz/newsletter.php

It also works in web mail clients.

Now Outlook. I only have Outlook 2010 to test it, but the page is completely messed up.
Image here: http://pbrd.co/1kwPtsv

For some reason the images are larger (in means of width and height) than it's written in code (and they original size). They are even larger than original size of them which is weird. All the images have the right sizes as original, but outlook somehow makes them bigger.

So if there's a way to tell outlook to don't enlarge images, that would be great. Or some other advice.

Ty

Comment: Background images are pretty much a dead loss in HTML email. Outlook doesn't support them. Check out this guide: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: that is why don't use background image while making a mailer. Outlook still doesn't support background images. In addition would be better if you use inline style.

Answer (score 0):

So I found why the images were bigger in FAQ here http://backgrounds.cm/:

> Why is my background image scaled up or down in Outlook?
>
> Unlike most other email clients and browsers, Outlook 2007/2010/2013
>   uses the DPI of your background image to determine the scale. So to
>   make sure it renders at the right size, set the image's resolution to
>   96 DPI.

My images were 72DPI, so that was the problem. The layout is still pretty messy, but images are now OK.